# How to check access number in binary format?

Tags: java, binary

I have created access in number format :

```
1 ( bynary format is -  1  )
2 (  10 )
4  (  100 )
8  (  1000 )
16 ( 10000 )
32 (  100000 )
64 ( 1000000 )
```

Then when I want to add access 1, 2, 8 and 32 I do  this operation `1 & 2 & 8 & 32`

```
    int x = 1 | 2 | 8 | 32;  // 43
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));  // 101011
```

How to check that x has '8' access ?

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the issue you are having troubles with?

Comment: @zloctb please refrain from such comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bit-wise **AND**:

```
boolean hasEight = (x & 8) == 8;
```

Let's use your example:

```
int x = 1 | 2 | 8 | 32;  // 43
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));  // 101011

boolean hasEight = (x & 8) == 8; // 0b101011 & 0b1000 will result in 0b1000
assert hasEight;
```

If your value doesn't contain the "eight" flag, the result will be `0` instead

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy to do this you can set up a `lambda` to check if all specified bits are set in a target.

```
        BiFunction<Integer,Integer, Boolean> test =
                  (bits, target)-> (target & bits) == bits;
```

The bit pattern is the first argument and the target is the second argument.

```
        System.out.println(test.apply(8,8));  //true
        System.out.println(test.apply(8,15)); //true
        System.out.println(test.apply(12,17)); // false
        System.out.println(test.apply(12,8));// false
        System.out.println(test.apply(12,29)); //true
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer:** You can Use "&".

```
//Want to check if x has access to 8
if ((x & 8)!=0) {//has access}
else {//doesn't}
```

**Explanation:** This action is called masking. when you want to check if a certain bit is set, you may and the number(bit sequence) with a number whose binary representation contains only one 1 which is the bit we want to check.
You can use *masking* for multiple bits.
**Example:** Is 4th bit of 37 set (to one)?
0b100101 (37 in binary form)
0b001000
--------------
0b000000

Comment: Even though my answer is correct, I get a negative reputation. I just ask more experienced user what is wrong with how I answer the questions. Help please.